# Change validation settings for specific form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Consider the `form` that are loaded via AJAX. After appending the `form` to the document I'm calling

```js
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

and the client validation works like a charm. However there are some scenarios, when I need to change the validation settings, like `ignore`, so I call

```
$form.validate({
    ignore: ''
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form); // and parse with new settings
```

In this case unobtrusive client validation just doesn't work. What could be the issue?

**Edit**

"Doesn't work" means, `$form.valid()` is always `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form); // parse the form
var validator = $.data($form[0], 'validator'); // get the form's validator
validator.settings.ignore = ''; // change its settings
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help.

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
   @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }</div>
```